# google admin api - client_secrets error

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I was playing around with google admin api and put the example code together with a little modification.  I set things up correctly on the google end, but when I run the script it kept giving me errors.  Below is my code in python:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
SERVICE = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))


results = SERVICE.users().list(customer='my_customer', maxResults=10,
    orderBy='email').execute()
users = results.get('users', [])
```

Error I am getting is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 11, in <module>
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/oauth2client/client.py", line 2125, in flow_from_clientsecrets
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 165, in loadfile
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 126, in _loadfile
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 101, in _validate_clientsecrets
oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: Missing property "client_secret" in a client type of "installed".
```

I am new to google api and would very much appreciate for any helps.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out.  Googles docs are crap.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I've found is with the name of Google's **OAuth 2.0 client IDs**. For your client ID, the **name** must **EXACTLY** be `Google Sheets API Quickstart`, or else the `"client_secret"` won't be populated in the `client_secret.json` when you download it from Google.

Alternatively, you could manually add a property under the `installed` JSON object, such as `"client_secret":"mysupercoolsecret"`, using the secret generated for the credential when you made the credential.

Either way, I have no idea why Google would only populate the `"client_secret"` field when the ***name*** of the credential doesn't match a certain value.

Hope this helps. I've encounter this issue with using the Google API for other languages as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to click RESET SECRET button in the JSON Download page.
[image]

After that, you will have a brand new Client Secret and auto generated in your Json file.

[image]

I just encountered this same exact problem, and solved it this way. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Download the `client_secret.json` again. There is a problem with that file.

You can use [this link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name) for a small tutorial to get your `client_secret`.